# Check current user id

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have model with `ManyToMany` field, that hooked up the user... So, I need `if-else` function in my template, that can check is currently authenticated user connected to model, or not. I tried to do that, but do something wrong...

My model `article`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'article'

    article_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    article_content = models.IntegerField(choices=CONTENT_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

My `views.py` for that:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect, Http404
from article.models import Article
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template import RequestContext

# Create your views here.
def article(request, article_id=1):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['article'] = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
    args['username'] = auth.get_user(request).username
    users = args['article'].article_users
    return render_to_response('article.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And template:

```
{% if article.article_users = user %}
<p>Purchased</p>
{% else %}
<input type="submit" value="Buy">
{% endif %}
```

**EDIT:**

```
{% if user in article.article_users %}
    <p>Purchased</p>
{% else %}
    <input type="submit" value="Buy">
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
{% if user in article.article_users %}
```

Comment: Under the `EDIT` - my updated template. And it still doesn't work... User hooked up to article and its balance changed too after purchase, but I still see the input button, but not `<p>...</p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
# user -- current user
#article.article_users -- article users
{% if user in article.article_users %}
```

should do the intended checking.

Comment: Under the `EDIT` - my updated template. And it still doesn't work... User hooked up to article and its balance changed too after purchase, but I still see the input button, but not `<p>...</p>` tag

Comment: Can you print/show the article.article_users values on template?

Comment: How can I do that? If you mean something like `{{ article.article_users }}`, I got `No exception message supplied`. If I put something like `{{ article.article_users.user.username }}` - I got no errors, but no info too... Or I made something wrong?